# Absolute positioning of an image next to page title in MediaWiki

Tags: css, mediawiki

How to absolute position (i.e. relative to browser window) an element in a MediaWiki article with wikicode and css?

What I need to do is put some icons in the empty space of the header area. For instance, in my movies wiki, in "Star Trek" articles I want to put a Star Trek logo up there that will act as a second logo, next to wiki's logo, creating the impression that we are in a sub-site inside the wiki, linking to home page of that sub-site, the Star Trek portal. And so on; for each group of movies there will be a different logo (X-Files, Star Wars etc). So this must be done with a simple template and not touching the skin (which is the Vector btw).

I've tried

```
<div style="
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 100;>{{logo}}</div>
```

but this absolute positions the logo to the **top left corner of the content area**, *not the browser window!*

I've also tried to put all this inside other container divs with all possible positioning and displaying but it seems I can't get out of the content area no matter what.

So the workround I've found is to change `top` to `-150px;` so that the logo would go to the desired place. But since this is actually **relative to content area**, if an article's title is too big and breaks into two lines, then the logo appears in a lower place following the content area that's also moved.

My guess is that MediaWiki uses some kind of code that makes the content area act as being the browser window or something. If that's the case, is there a way to override this? With a LocalSettings.php switch maybe?

Comment: You could edit the markup or something, to avoid absolutely position elements. Your solution is breaking because `position: absolute` will be absolute towards the next relatively positioned parent.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It point me to the right direction! I realised I should look up the chain of parents to look for a relative position. I found class `.mw-body-content` which I then set to `position: static;` in MediaWiki:Common.css and now absolute positioning of logo seems to work as desired! I hope this change won't break skin's integrity. So far I've noticed no issues with 'static'. Maybe someone with experience in Vector can tell us if it's ok.

Comment: Try resizing the window to make sure it looks good :) I'm going to turn my comment into an answer so you can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: There seem to be no issues when resizing (considering of course that Vector skin itself is not mobile optimized so header tabs break anyway under 800-900px width <- that depending on the locale, for instance "Edit" in Greek is "Επεξεργασία", almost 3 times wider, so in Greek tabs break faster). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Haha, that made me laugh. I work for a company with a localized website, and things in German break very quickly, maybe even faster than Greek ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, try to avoid `position: absolute`. In tends to break as the window resizes.

Your attempts are probably breaking because `position: absolute` will be absolute towards the next relatively positioned parent. Go up the DOM tree for that particular element to find a parent that is positioned `relative`.

Answer (score 1):

In MediaWiki 1.25 and later you should use [page indicators](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Page_status_indicators).

The wikitext you need is simply `<indicator name="logo">{{logo}}</indicator>` assuming `{{logo}}` contains the image in question.

Comment: Thanks @Nemo ! I'm still below 1.25 but I think that page indicators is a great feature addition and makes life easier for those wanting to put an extra logo/image to their sites. And if you want to put it anywhere else on the header I guess that from indicator position would be much easier to absolute position it because indicator has a fixed distance from top despite whether page title would be one line long or several ones.